# Android run service and check on specific days and possibly create a notification

Tags: android, android-service

I'm trying to create a service on Android.
This service should check on specific days (example: wednesday, friday and sunday at 11 am) if the control is true then it should create a notification.

Anyone have any idea on how to do?

Comment: Please post your findings or work.

Comment: What problem you are facing with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a JobScheduler that trigger running a service on a specific time 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html